# How to use loop on js to let style.display = "none"

Tags: javascript, loops

I want use loop to run the following code but i get **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'display')** on chrome

```
    tempComboBox_0_ListItem.style.display = "none";
    tempComboBox_1_ListItem.style.display = "none";
    tempComboBox_2_ListItem.style.display = "none";
```

This is loop code

```
for (let i = 0; i < DataGrid_ListItem.length; i++)
    {
        "tempComboBox_" + i + "_ListItem".style.display == "none";
    }
```

This is ascx code

```
<div onmousemove="mouseMove_ListItem()" id="ListItem" style="border-right: #0099cc 1px solid; padding-right: 1px; border-top: medium none; overflow-y: scroll; display: none; scrollbar-face-color: #c9ddf5; border-left: #0099cc 1px solid; width: 300px; scrollbar-shadow-color: #0099cc; scrollbar-3dlight-color: #0099cc; scrollbar-arrow-color: #0099cc; scrollbar-track-color: #f0f8ff; border-bottom: #0099cc 1px solid; scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #f0f8ff; height: 100px; background-color: #f4f8ff"
onclick="onClick_ListItem()" onmouseout="mouseout_ListItem()" runat="server">
<asp:DataGrid ID="DataGrid_ListItem" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%"></asp:DataGrid>
```

I use DataGrid_ListItem.length to decide how many ListItem

Can someone can tell me why it is wrong?

Thanks

update:
I revise this to answer my queation

```
for (let i = 0; i < DataGrid_ListItem.length; i++)
    {
        var ListItem1 = eval("document.all." + "tempComboBox_" + i + "_ListItem");
        ListItem1.style.display = "none";
    }
```

Comment: Add you html code

Comment: Don't store those values in separate variables. Store them in an array and loop over the array.

Answer (score 0):

So using the loop that you have already you can do it this way. That is if your DataGrid_ListItem is an array of the elements that you are trying to add the style to.

```
for (let i = 0; i < DataGrid_ListItem.length; i++)
    {
        DataGrid_ListItem[i].style.display == "none";
    }
```

Comment: I update my question ,
I use DataGrid_ListItem.length to decide how many ListItem

Answer (score -1):

You can use forEach() method to achieve the desired result.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#id, #id1, #id2').forEach(item => {
    item.style = 'none';
})
```

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('#id4, #id5, #id6').style = none would also achive this

Comment: I try use
for (let i = 0; i < DataGrid_ListItem.length; i++)
        {
            document.querySelectorAll("tempComboBox_" + i + "_ListItem").style = "none";
        }
but it's not working

Comment: @willy99924 Why do you think `document.querySelectorAll("tempComboBox_" + i + "_ListItem").style = "none"` makes sense? Please read the documentation: [`querySelectorAll`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), [`style`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style), and see [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](/q/10693845/4642212).

Comment: Reread my answer please and do as it says